# Disable the YT share button in my website of HTML

Tags: button, video, share, yt

I tried to remove the share button of my yt video but i am unable to do that so if any one know how to disable it please help me

Comment: Post the code that you tried that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The only way to prevent sharing of a video is to [make it private](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: But i can't view it in my website if i make it private